# Purging all pages in mediawiki

Tags: caching, mediawiki, purge

Is it possible to purge all pages in mediawiki? I've tried emptying the obejctcache table to no avail. I don't particularly want to hit each page with `?action=purge` appended. Version 1.23.3

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww the simple fact the question is over a year old, not closed and has upvotes and answers with votes would suggest to you that a) it's a suitable question which is useful to the community or b) is in dire need of being closed. And besides, this question is about development of a mediawiki site which involved programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either

1. Use the maintainance script [PurgeList.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PurgeList.php) like this: `php purgeList.php --purge --all`, for MW > 1.21, and `php purgeList.php --all-namespaces` for MW > 1.34. Really old MW versions do not have the `--all` option, so you will need a list of pages.
2. Use the API: [API:Purge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Purge#Purging_pages.27_caches), and feed it with a list of all pages (that you can get from [API:Allpages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages))
3. Invalidate all caches by [setting `$wgCacheEpoch` to the current time](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheEpoch) in LocalSettings.php, e.g.
   `$wgCacheEpoch = 20140901104232;`.
4. Set `$wgInvalidateCacheOnLocalSettingsChange` (since MW 1.17) to achieve pretty much the same thing. *Only do this if your wiki has low to moderate traffic*.
5. Not sure if this is a good idea, but if you have access to the wiki's database you should also be able to achieve the same effect by truncating the table `objectcache`.

Comment: `php purgeList.php --purge --all` does nothing in my case. I can't find a way to permanently delete all the pages. ((

Comment: @zhekaus This question is not about deleting pages, but about purging their caches

Comment: This is `php purgeList.php --all-namespaces` for MW 1.34+

Answer (score 6):

Invalidate all caches for all sites with this simple command:

```
touch /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
```

because in the touch `LocalSettings.php` file there is this part:

```
# When you make changes to this configuration file, this will make
# sure that cached pages are cleared.
$wgCacheEpoch = max( $wgCacheEpoch, gmdate( 'YmdHis', @filemtime( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

`__FILE__` is the `LocalSettings.php` file itself, so if the filetime is now, all cache older than the file will be purged.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Note that this is not part of `LocalSettings.php` since MW 1.17. Instead, there is a setting called `$wgInvalidateCacheOnLocalSettingsChange` that will achieve pretty much the same. This method is great for smaller wikis, but [not recommended](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgInvalidateCacheOnLocalSettingsChange) for high traffic wikis.

Answer (score 0):

Use [purgePage.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PurgePage.php) as the equivalent to `action=purge`